# Bigcommerce redirect to login if logged out

Tags: javascript, redirect, cookies, authentication, bigcommerce

We are needing to check if a user visiting the site is logged in. If not, they must be redirected to the login screen. I've attempted a JS solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29013967/5986598), but the console is still spitting out `the user is not logged in` even if they are.

I've checked the cookie BigCommerce use and it does appear to still use `LoginEmail`

```
//this will allow you to mention the cookie by index
function getCookie(name) {
  var value = "; " + document.cookie;
  var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
  if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}
//set variable that will check if login email exists
var loggedIn = getCookie('LoginEmail');

//logic that will output different content based on the loggedIn Status
if(typeof loggedIn === 'undefined'){
    console.log("They are not logged in!");
    window.location.replace("/login.php");
}
else{
    console.log("They are logged in! ");
}
```

I am triggering this on the homepage with Stencil. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean that if someone visit to your website the visitor must be login to view your website?

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj Yeah pretty much. I ended up going for a different approach by detecting the `sign in` button div `guest-user` and if true, redirect to login.php. When the user is signed in the `guest-user` div disappears because of the `if` statement in stencil.

Answer (score 1):

There is an endpoint that will check to see if the user is logged in, and from there you can process the response as needed.  I've included a snippet below:

```html
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ( this.readyState == 4 ) {
            if (this.status == 200) {
                callback(JSON.parse(this.responseText))
            } else {
                callback(null);
            }
        }
    };
 
    xhttp.open('GET', "/customer/current.jwt?app_client_id=' + clientId");
    xhttp.send();
```